# Hierarchical clustering Ward's method. The missing rationale in derivation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, ward

The Ward's method is taking distance as how much the sum of squares will increase when we merge them.

$d(u,v) = \frac{|u||v|}{|u|+|v|}{|m_u-m_v|}^2$

Please refer to Page 3 of link below.

https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjz06z524bXAhVCurwKHUfvD5wQFgg0MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.cmu.edu%2F~cshalizi%2F350%2Flectures%2F08%2Flecture-08.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0hrIiXitAkxr5Ciur0hQkf

But, from Scipy implementation from github.
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py

The distance is derived as below.

$d(u,v) = \sqrt{\frac{|v|+|s|}{T}d(v,s)^2 + \frac{|v|+|t|}{T}d(v,t)^2- \frac{|v|}{T}d(s,t)^2}$

I am wondering what happend between these two equations.
They even do not result same value for the same merge.

I tested on merging [(0,0),(0,2)] and [(2,0)].
Upper one gives me value of 3.333...
Bottom one gives me values of 2.581988...

Why they have difference?

Comment: +1 to Anony's answer. Read also the Talk page of Wikipedia article of Ward method.

Comment: @ttnphns Sure, I have read the Wikipedia first. But that doesn't explain the gap between two equations.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that there is a 'Talk' session, not 'article'. Thanks for your information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than reverse engineering the code, also check for references and literature. These algorithms often long predate sklearn.

Even Wikipedia has this equation, known as **Lance Williams** equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method

If I'm not mistaken, a subtle difference is that it works on the *squared* distances and uses the *increase* in variance, not the resulting variance.

The two means of the merged clusters are (0,1) and (2,0), so the first equation yields ⅔(2²+1²)=10/3=3⅓ (same as you got).

For the Lance Williams result, we need the squared distance first, which are 4 respectively 8. We then get ⅔.4+⅔.8-⅓.4=20/3. As mentioned on the Wikipedia talk page, there is the constant factor of 2 involved here.

Now sqrt(20/3) is just the value you got. You had one distance squared, and one non-squared, and the factor of two was missing.

Comment: I really appreciate for your kind answer! It helps me a lot. I got that equations are in some relation by factor 2. But, can we derive this?

Comment: That is why I suggest to do a literature review. Someone (maybe Lance & William?) probably published the derivation.

Comment: The factor of 2 probably comes from the difference of "sum over all i and j" with and without order (i.e., sum over all i<j) if you derive the equations from all pairwise distances, you will supposedly get the factor of 2 when going from the sums to the difference in means. I.e. the derivation in that lecture notes probably lost the factor 2.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. That seems where the factor 2 comes from. Just one more thing, can you recommend me some reference in literature?

Comment: HAC and Ward's method are so old, there are thousands of publications on it. It's pretty interesting to study the early publications. But I can't point out particular ones.